# What happens when you try to delete a list element while iterating over it

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-internals

I'm iterating a list as follows:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
another_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for idx, item in enumerate(some_list):
    del some_list[idx]

for item in another_list:
    another_list.remove(item)
```

When I print out the contents of the lists

```
>>> some_list
[2, 4]
>>> another_list
[2, 4]
```

I'm aware that Python doesn't support modifying a `list` while iterating over it and the right way is to iterate over copy of list instead. But I want to know what exactly happens behind the scenes i.e. Why is the output of the above snippet `[2, 4]`?

Comment: Have you run this using a debugger or something like http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html?

Comment: I've run this using ipython shell.

Comment: Wait, why is this question downvoted? It is bad iterating and deleting, but that output is puzzling to me.

Comment: first item is removed, then list is shifted to the left, so index is increased and second item is spared. And so on.

Comment: @Abdou It's probably downvoted because the OP hasn't tried to figure it out, e.g. by running it in a debugger or something like pythontutor.com/visualize.html ...

Comment: Ah! It's the reindexing thing!

Comment: https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/ looks like python also has undefined behaviour

Comment: @thebjorn sometimes even with a visualizer, it may be tough for a beginner to grasp what's going on. Also, this is one of those questions that strengthen the argument that you should not delete from a list during iteration.

Comment: @Abdou I didn't downvote, but this should be understandable by printing the state of the variables in the for-loop. Many, me included, think that is a basic step you ought to do before asking -- but as I said, I didn't downvote :-)

Comment: related: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a self-made iterator that shows (in this case `print`s) the state of the iterator:

```
class CustomIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
        self.idx = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        print('give next element:', self.idx)
        for idx, item in enumerate(self.seq):
            if idx == self.idx:
                print(idx, '--->', item)
            else:
                print(idx, '    ', item)
        try:
            nxtitem = self.seq[self.idx]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.idx += 1
        return nxtitem

    next = __next__  # py2 compat
```

Then use it around the list you want to check:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for idx, item in enumerate(CustomIterator(some_list)):
    del some_list[idx]
```

This should illustrate what happens in that case:

```
give next element: 0
0 ---> 1
1      2
2      3
3      4
give next element: 1
0      2
1 ---> 3
2      4
give next element: 2
0      2
1      4
```

It only works for sequences though. It's more complicated for mappings or sets.

Comment: @thebjorn yes, but iterating over them and changing them (while keeping the size constant) can lead to interesting stuff: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877614/how-to-change-all-the-dictionary-keys-in-a-for-loop-with-d-items and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489688/can-anyone-explain-this-bizarre-bug-iterating-over-a-set. It's much harder to visualize (that was what I was referring to) because the internal set/dict structure isn't exposed from within Python.

Comment: That reminded me of a quote by Rick Cook (https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rick_Cook) :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know what exactly happens behind the scenes

As we know, every item in a list lives at its own unique index; which are in order, starting from 0. If we remove an item, any item with an index greater than the one we've removed has now been shifted down.

**And here's why that matters:**

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for index in range(len(foo)):
    del foo[index]
```

In this loop, we're removing all the elements, so we should end up with `foo == []`, right? This is not the case. In our first trip through the loop, we remove the item at index `0`, and the item at index `1` *becomes the item at index `0`*. Our next time through the loop, we remove *the item at index `1`* which was *previously the item at index 2*.

In just the first two iterations, we've removed `'a'` and `'c'` from the array, *but we've neglected to remove `'b'`. Once we get to the third iteration (where we though we'd remove index `2`), there is *no longer an element at index `2`*; only indices `0` and `1`. An exception is raised when we try to remove the non-existent item at index `2`, and the loop is stopped. The result is a mangled array that looks like this: `['a', 'd']`.