# Removing dictionaries from list with for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this sample list of dictionaries below. I want to know why the below code will only loop over two values in the list? Why does it not loop over every value in the list?

```
updated_list_of_site_dicts = [{'site': 'living', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'keg', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'box', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'wine', 'status': 'ready' }]

for site_dict in updated_list_of_site_dicts:
    if site_dict['status'] == 'ready':
        print site_dict['site'] + " is ready"
        updated_list_of_site_dicts.remove(site_dict)
        print updated_list_of_site_dicts
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python for\_in loop to print the last item in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086441/python-for-in-loop-to-print-the-last-item-in-the-list)

Comment: This is helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating/1208792#1208792

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to update instead:

```
updated_list_of_site_dicts = [d for d in updated_list_of_site_dicts 
                              if d['status'] != 'ready']
```

Note that in your current example, you have all 'ready' so you'll get an empty list.  Here's an example where one status isn't ready:

```
updated_list_of_site_dicts = [{'site': 'living', 'status': 'ready' }, 
                              {'site': 'keg', 'status': 'ready' }, 
                              {'site': 'box', 'status': 'ready' }, 
                              {'site': 'wine', 'status': 'NOT READY' }]

for d in updated_list_of_site_dicts:
    if d['status'] == 'ready':
        print(d['site'] + " is ready")
living is ready
keg is ready
box is ready

updated_list_of_site_dicts = [d for d in updated_list_of_site_dicts 
                              if d['status'] != 'ready']
print(updated_list_of_site_dicts)
[{'site': 'wine', 'status': 'NOT READY'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It loops only twice because [remove()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method causes list indexes to shift.

If you want to loop the list and remove elements you should iterate the list in reverse order. Such as;

```
updated_list_of_site_dicts = [{'site': 'living', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'keg', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'box', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'wine', 'status': 'ready' }]

for i in range(len(updated_list_of_site_dicts) - 1, -1, -1): 
    site_dict = updated_list_of_site_dicts[i]
    if site_dict['status'] == 'ready':
        print site_dict['site'] + " is ready"
        updated_list_of_site_dicts.remove(site_dict)
        print updated_list_of_site_dicts
```

Also, if you only want to remove elements you can use filter too.

```
>>> updated_list_of_site_dicts = [{'site': 'living', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'keg', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'box', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'wine', 'status': 'ready' }, {'site': 'can', 'status': 'not_ready' }]
>>> updated_list_of_site_dicts = filter(lambda x: x['status'] != 'ready', updated_list_of_site_dicts)
>>> updated_list_of_site_dicts
[{'status': 'not_ready', 'site': 'can'}]
```