# Interior grouping within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def gp(inp): #group positives in the list
  for x in range(len(inp)-1):
    if is_pos(inp[x][0]) and is_pos(inp[x+1][0]): 
      inp[x] += inp[x+1]
      del inp[x+1]
```

I work in python. That code above is for grouping together adjacent positives. I think this question would appeal to other people because of the error I received. What would that error be? an IndexError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 95, in <module>
  File "python", line 49, in formt
  File "python", line 10, in gp
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What I am trying to achieve is to group a list that looks like this: `[[1],[2],[3],[-4],[-3],[-2],[-1],[0]]`
into what looks like this: `[[1,2,3],[-4,-3,-2,-1],[0]]` I have no other imports, and this doesn't call to any other functions. How would I go about doing this, and why am I receiving that error? My theory is that it lies in `range(len(inp))` but I've tried experimenting with it a lot and no luck. The brackets around each individual number are intentional, so that I could combine numbers into lists by "adding" them. If you have a different way, please tell me. I want this to be about interior grouping in general, so try to generalize what I did wrong to that.

Comment: This is for a machine learning library, and grouping together the positives is an important step in my process. I wish I could explain why, but that'd be a very long comment.

Comment: You are deleting a list element, while iterating over it. Don't do this. [See for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45946228/8881141)

Comment: what would happen if you have a list `[[1],[-1],[1]]` would you love it as it is?

Comment: Is 0 assumed to be a positive number?

Comment: The standard `itertools` module has a `groupby` function that's good for tasks like this.

Comment: What igle said. Do zeroes go in their own group, or do they get grouped with positive integers?

Comment: 0 is assumed to be positive. Sorry I wasn't clear about it

Comment: Since the list is a list of differences, 0 is considered as no difference and is considered positive to make it easier on the machine

Comment: I wish I could explain it better, but the entire library is complicated and a few hundred lines long

Comment: After all this, I still don't know, if `[[1], [-1], [2], [-2], [3]]` should left as is or should result in `[[1, 2, 3], [-1, -2]]`

Comment: @Piinthesky `[[1], [-1], [2], [-2], [3]]` would be preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do it using itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

def gp(inp):
    return [
        list(things)  # groupby yields iterators
        for _, things  # throw away the truth value
        # chain to remove the nesting
        in groupby(inp, lambda x: x<0)
    ]
```

Usage:

```
>>> gp([1, 2, 3, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0])
[[1, 2, 3], [-4, -3, -2, -1], [0]]
```

If you consider 0 its own class, you can get away with a little bit of hackiness by replacing the `lambda x: x<0` with `lambda x: x*float("inf")`:

```
>>> gp_new([1, 2, 3, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
[[1, 2, 3], [-4, -3, -2, -1], [0], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: You should also show the simpler version that works with a flat list. The OP is only using that list of lists to simplify the task of merging groups.

Comment: You can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to avoid unpacking the list.

Comment: I removed the more complicated version

Comment: How come this doesn't group 0 with the *positive* numbers? Both return `False` on the `lambda` check..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis negative numbers are smaller than 0 and therefore return `True`

Comment: @L3viathan I meant positive. Btw changing the `>` to `<` does group them..

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know itertools had this function.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Oh, because groupby only groups consecutive elements with the same "value"

Comment: @L3viathan Then this solution only works under the assumption that some sort of *sorting* pre-exists in the list. Not sure if that is what OP wanted. For that reason, I like the `x*float('inf')` much better. I think this should be the main answer.

Comment: @L3viathan I think he made it clear that he wants it alone. That is my understanding of it at least. Anyway +1.

Comment: @L3viathan actually, I prefer the 0 to be joined with positive but it makes no real difference